# Trim a character string until a specific character appears

Tags: regex, r

I am reading in a bunch of files from a folder, merge them into a data frame, and then save that data frame "outside" of that folder. E.g.

```
# path to folder that contains files to read in:
path <- "/path/to/folder"

# read in files
files <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)

# do stuff with files
...

# safe data frame
path.2 <- "/path/to/"
write.csv2(paste0(path.2, "dat.csv"), dat)
```

No sweat.

But I want to be able to change the value for the variable `path`, without having to manually change the value for `path.2`, too. I want to **automatically assign `path.2` the value of `path`, minus the folder name, without having to tell R the name of that folder**. That is, I need to trim all characters from the right end of the string in `path`, until the file separator ("/").

Pseudocode:

```
path <- "/path/to/folder"
path.2 <- rtrim(path, to = "/")
path.2
[1] "/path/to/"
```

How can I go about that?

Comment: why don't you specify `path2` first and then use paste to create `path`?

Comment: @NBATrends I'm creating a script that will be used by different people on different computers with different folders in different locations. I want that they have to adapt just one value in the script (the path to the folder with the files), otherwise the written explanation will become too complicated to follow. With your suggestion, they would have to define both the path to the folder and the folder name separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sub`,

```
sub('/([^/]*)$', '', path)
#[1] "/path/to"
```

Or using `str_extract` from `stringr` package,

```
str_extract(path, '^(?:[^/]*/){3}')
#[1] "/path/to/"
```

Comment: Your second example (with `str_extract`) works only on paths that are exactly three folders deep. The first is nice. Thank you.

Comment: I thought the case was always 3, hence the `{3}` :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
path <- "/path/to/folder"
paste(head(unlist(strsplit(path, "/", fixed = TRUE)), -1), collapse = "/")

# [1] "/path/to"
```